# how to select a file for reopening by creating list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got how to obtain a list of files using Ajax and php.but I wanted to select one of those files and open it.

so I wanted to get a list in which I can select any file of the users choice.

Answer (score 0):

Put your list in a <select> field with each file as an <option> with value equal to the file name. Then make an onchange event (or a submission function, if you want them to complete other elements of a form first) that sends the name of the selected file via ajax to a php script that uses fopen() to open the file and manipulate it however you want.